# C# WinForms Show E-mail Message to user

Tags: c#, winforms, email, client

So, I've this POP3/SMTP e-mail client I'm making as my internship project, and I need to show the e-mails to the user. The e-mails are already downloaded and stored in the file-system, with the URI stored inside a database table.

So which would be the best method to show the E-mail to the user?

Thank you in advance.

João Borrego.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. If you only want to show plain text, you'd go for `TextBox` or `RichTextBox`. If you also want to show HTML content, you'd need to go for the `WebBrowser` control.

Comment: I'd like to show also the HTML content, so WebBrowser control! :D However, I'd like to know, will OpenPop Mime parser (used OpenPop to download the messages) and the WebBrowser Control work well with each other?

Comment: Have you tried? :-) I don't know OpenPop, so I can't tell you. Luckily, this isn't part of the original question ;-)

Comment: I'm trying it out right now... I'll say if it worked once I finish it! =D